# ruby version error while creating react native project

Tags: ruby, react-native, macos

I'm trying to create a new react native project on my mac but getting this error though I have ruby version 3.1.2. How can I resolve this?

```
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing Bundler
error Your Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified >= 2.6.10

✖ Installing Bundler
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
Error: Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
    at createFromTemplate (/Users/tanjilpranto/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:131:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.initialize [as func] (/Users/tanjilpranto/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:184:3)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/tanjilpranto/.npm/_npx/dea611a43221eddd/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:106:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
tanjilpranto@Tanjils-MacBook-Pro ~ % ruby -v
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-darwin21]
tanjilpranto@Tanjils-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

I tried using rbenv, rvm but still the same happening everytime

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75942257/3784008 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74942677/3784008

Comment: still having the same issue after trying that

Comment: That response isn’t good enough. State *specifically* what you have done — EXACT STEPS — and the outcomes of those changes. I say that because your question is incredibly common and identical to multiple other questions asked even in the last few months. If the common solutions to those questions don’t work for you then either 1) you didn’t share what makes your situation unique or 2) you didn’t actually follow the steps in those answers. I suspect 2.

Comment: I followed exactly what was told in that answer even though I followed the steps from react docs and still got the same error 'Your Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified >= 2.6.10". I tried with rvm, rbenv to install ruby version 3.1.2 and made it global as well as local for specific folder. When I look for ruby version it is showing 3.1.2 but when I'm creating react native project its showing the error.

Comment: I’m no longer willing to help you since you refused to follow clear instructions. Good luck and don’t expect to get an answer to this question that has been asked and solved many times before on this site.

Comment: I already said I followed the instructions you provided with two links & still having issues.
My steps were:
1. Installed homebrew
2. Installed node, watchman, rbenv (already have Xcode)
3. using rbenv installed ruby 3.1.2
4. made it global and local (set path also for zsh,bash)
5. Tried creating a new project "npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject"

now it's showing the error I already described.

but when I do 'ruby -v' it's showing that 3.1.2 then how it's getting 2.6.8?

Still, if you didn't get it then it's fine, I'll figure that out somehow. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you add the command you ran?

Comment: Hey, it's running now. Though still, it's getting errors while creating new projects but when I install pod and bundle inside the project it's running. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

install react native like this npx react-native@latest init project name after that rename your gem file in react native with ruby version 2.7.5 this works for me
like this ruby "2.7.5" hope this helps